# Iterating over an array without initialization

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have a hash `PAYMENT_TYPES_HASH`. Is there a way to create an array from this hash using `each` without declaring the array before it like `a = []`?

```
a = [];
PAYMENT_TYPES_HASH.each {|order| a << [order[:name], order[:id]]}
a
```

Something like this:

```
array = PAYMENT_TYPES_HASH.each {|order| do something to return the array}
```

Comment: Is payment type a hash, or an array of hashes?

Comment: I want an array of arrays like this [['name', 'id'], ['name2', 'id2']]

Comment: Is there any particular reason not to use `#map`?

Comment: yeah @Yossi!!! you're right!! thanks! post a answer for me to vote you up!

Comment: @Yossi can you vote up this question too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `#map` method:

```
PAYMENT_TYPES_HASH.map {|order| [order[:name], order[:id]]}
```